# apply_filters, EMBEDS and AJAX not a friends?

Tags: ajax, filters

I encountered a problem...

There is content that contains a YouTube link

> Lorem ipsum bla bla bla http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTDNLUzjkpg

My plugin display this content with that code in the view:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $data['meta']->start_page_content ); ?>
```

The problem is that if you open a page with usual GET method via the browser - the link becomes a YouTube player, but when i loaded the same template via AJAX - it seems that apply_filters does not work - at the output I get just a link, not a YouTube player code.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't posted, what *exactly* you're doing with AJAX, we can just *guess*. And I guess, that you're doing it extremly wrong - no need to "hook/filter" in ajax.

#### AJAX is for admin(?)

Basically, AJAX stuff is meant to be admin stuff. This means, that you got a `wp_ajax_` hook and a `wp_ajax_nopriv_` hook, but `is_admin()` will still return true for all requests. That's something that is left over, or just tradition.

If you want to add something via AJAX, than simply do it with javascript.

#### Use `wp_localize_script()` to transport data from PHP » javascript

First localize your meta data to make it usable in the script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', etc.... );
wp_localize_script(
     'my-script-handle'
    ,'my_localized_data'
    ,array(
        'youtubevideo' => $data['meta']->start_page_content
     )
);
```

#### Simple jQuery does it all

Then add it to the container, or wherever you need it:

```
// Depending on what exactly your "video" is (embed/link/etc.), you need to adjust the var.
var youtube_video = my_localized_data.youtubevideo;
jQuery( '#content' ).append( youtube_video );
```

Comment: my problem is that the function `apply_filters` does not work properly, not in AJAX call

Comment: @user16962 Filters don't work in AJAX calls... as I described and explained above ↑ : _»(...)no need to "hook/filter" in ajax.«_

Comment: okay... do you know the WP function, that converts standard EMBED links to their container code?

Comment: Search on Codex?

Comment: i have found `global $wp_embed;
echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $data['meta']->start_page_content);` with same probleb. it doesn't works when i load the content via AJAX :(

Comment: problem fixed!  `<?php global $wp_embed; $wp_embed->post_ID = $data['post_ID']; ?>
  <?php echo $wp_embed->run_shortcode( $data['taster_meta']->start_page_content ); ?>
`

Comment: Then add this to my answer (the part inside wp localize script) and mark it as solution.

Answer (score -1):

The oEmbed is not processed because of the lack of $post->ID (as global).
You can just do in your function :

`global $post;
$post->ID = PHP_INT_MAX;`

...and then the apply_filter( 'content' ...) will just work as if this was not an Ajax call.